# Can I use masking tape for 12V max insulation?

Tags: soldering, insulation

**Hello.** Would it work if I put masking tape over a solder joint as insulation which would carry 12V max? I'm connecting a general-purpose 3-12V AC adapter to some wires. ***Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In-tact plastic insulating tape can certainly insulate 12 volts without a worry. You need to make sure, though, that the tape cannot slip along the wires if you make a two-ended jointed (most tape will easily roll over the glue), fall off (if you make a single-ended (hairpin) joint and that sharp points (eg of solder) cannot break through the tape. Abrasion can also be an issue. In all, there are enough possibilities that, alone, it's not a long term solution to keeping two voltages apart if failure is unacceptable (for example, if a short might cause a fire).

Comment: Masking tape is typically paper not plastic.

Comment: I apologise for misreading the question as insulating rather than masking tape. I would delete the answer, but now cannot as it has been accepted. All that I said stands for masking tape, though. The risk of a sharp point punching through would be much higher, though and the glue is typically much less sticky.

Comment: Masking tape hardens over time. The adhesive stops sticking and the tape can slide along the wire. I'd only use it for temporary connections.